# How to store multi-type data in NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsarray

```
NSArray *pets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cat", @"Dog", @"Rat", nil];
```

// how do I store int value 456 in this array after @"Rat" object, + pet is of type NSString so will not it generate error in while loop...??? so what data-type should i use for pet pointer that can represent all nextObject values/objects

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [pets objectEnumerator];
NSString *pet;

while (pet = [enumerator nextObject]) {
NSLog(@"Pet: %@", pet);
}
```

Comment: The above should be @[@"foo",@1,@YES]; 

@1 and @YES are converted to NSNumber, and are available via integerValue and boolValue methods on those NSNumber objects respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `NSArray` will only hold object you can not add an integer, you will need to wrap it in a `NSNumber`.

```
NSArray *pets = @[@"Cat", @"Dog", @"Rat", @456];
```

This will work with the loop you have in your example, but if you want to call any `NSString` method you will need to check the type:

```
for(id pet in pets) {

  if(![pet isKindOfClass:[NSString class]) {
     // It not a string, just continue to the next object. 
     continue;
  }
}
```

Or a while loop:

```
id pet;
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [pets objectEnumerator];
while (pet = [enumerator nextObject]) {
   if(![pet isKindOfClass:[NSString class]) {
      // It not a string, just continue to the next object. 
      continue;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can later retrieve the integer value by using `intValue` method on the `NSNumber` object.

Comment: @GoGreen or better yet use `integerValue` which return a `NSInteger` and not an `int`.

Comment: not working, can u give me some more detailed code plz

Comment: @iOS_Developer Why don't you tell us whats not working. because the code is working.

Comment: but i need to create an NSArray not NSNumber

Comment: My code is still creating a `NSArray`, one with strings and numbers.

Comment: NSNumber *anInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:217];
NSArray *pets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cat", @"Dog", @"Rat",anInt, nil];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [pets objectEnumerator];
id *pet;

while (pet = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"Pet: %@", pet);
}

Comment: @iOS_Developer it is not `id *pet;` but `id pet; `

Comment: @rckoenes i want to learn the concept and working of enumerator in the given context plz tell me according to while loop not for loop

Comment: @iOS_Developer it will be almost the same code, check my updated answer.

Comment: @rckoenes  in  our ios applications what is meant by API, i m new user to ios and i m unable to understand API over internet material, plz help me.

Comment: API stands for [Application programming interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) whicih alows you to tlak to a or the system.

Answer (score -3):

1. Use `@456`, it's the same as `[NSNumber numberWithInt:456]`
2. Use id. i.e.:

   ```
   id pet;

   while (pet = [enumerator nextObject]) {

       NSLog(@"Pet: %@", pet); // maybe unsafe if only a subset of the objects in the array can execute the methods

       // if you want to unwrap the pet to the concrete class, cast it with (NSString *)pet
       // but make sure the object is of correct type
       if ([pet isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {// use isMemberOfClass for exactly this class and isKindOfClasses for this class and subclasses of it
           // here you are sure it is a NSString
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i thought of the similar thing at first

Comment: @Viktor Lexington  in  our ios applications what is meant by API, i m new user to ios and i m unable to understand API over internet material, plz help me.

Comment: @iOS_Developer If you use code from other people (Apple inlcuded) it is very helpful to know which methods etc. you should use. The API is exactly that. If you have the source code in Objective-C the API (Application Programming Interface) is the .h file. When you use a Framework like UIKit the API is the Documentation. The API from your code tells other developers which methods etc. they should use so it works properly and vice versa.